# Release database changeloglock programatically

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, liquibase

I have a springboot application that uses java and I want to have a command line command that releases databasechangelogs.

I was thinking about doing the query or just using java to call the mvn liquibase:releaseLocks command.

Is any of the possibilites viable?

This is how I run my migrations

```
  ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(MigrationsApplication.class, args);
  int exitCode = SpringApplication.exit(ctx, () -> 0);
  logger.info("All migrations were finished with success");
  System.exit(exitCode);
```

Comment: why do you need that? Usually lock applies when liquibase executes migration script, after that liquibase should release lock automatically

Comment: for when a migration is unexpectadly interrupted

Comment: ok, you run migration on app start up using maven liquibase plugin?

Comment: @DanilaZharenkov not sure if this is what you are asking but I run this way `ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(MigrationsApplication.class, args);
            int exitCode = SpringApplication.exit(ctx, () -> 0);

            logger.info("All migrations were finished with success");
            System.exit(exitCode);`

Comment: that not relates to liquibase itself. Let's start from the begining. Are you using maven as dependency manger?

Comment: @DanilaZharenkov yes I am

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233801/discussion-between-danila-zharenkov-and-fabio).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Java API of Liquibase.

```
java.sql.Connection connection = openConnection(); //your openConnection logic here
Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));
Liquibase liquibase = new liquibase.Liquibase("path/to/changelog.xml", new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);
liquibase.update(new Contexts(), new LabelExpression());
```

Source: https://www.liquibase.org/blog/3-ways-to-run-liquibase?_ga=2.169260328.887208231.1623768288-1838810704.1623768288

And here is the JavaDoc https://www.liquibase.org/javadoc/?_ga=2.169260328.887208231.1623768288-1838810704.1623768288

Comment: isn't update for running migrations? I want to release the database changeloglocks

Comment: also do you know if there is a method in the API for making a rollback ?

Comment: Yes. Simply checkout the JavaDoc for the class Liquibase https://www.liquibase.org/javadoc/liquibase/Liquibase.html

Answer (score 0):

As Simon mentioned in his answer, you could use Liquibase Java API anytime to achieve this.

Also, I don't see the need to release locks explicitly. Liquibase will auto release them on successful update.

Still just in case required, you can refer below code block:

```
//your openConnection logic here
java.sql.Connection connection = openConnection(); 
Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));

//This will access your changelog file and create liquibase object
Liquibase liquibase = new liquibase.Liquibase("path/to/changelog.xml", new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database); 

// You can set contexts here to execute required changesets
final Contexts contexts = new Contexts("yourcontext");

// This will execute update on your Database with executing changesets
liquibase.update(contexts, new LabelExpression()); 

// To release locks
liquibase.forceReleaseLocks();
```

Just a sample implementation (might help):

```
public void updateDb(String url, String login, String password, String diffFilePath, String driverClassName) throws Exception{
        Connection c = //create connection from url/login/password/driverClassName;
        Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));
        Liquibase liquibase = new liquibase.Liquibase("path/to/changelog.xml", new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database); 
        try {
            liquibase.update(new Contexts("contexts"));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DatabaseException(e);
        } finally {
            if (liquibase != null) {
                liquibase.forceReleaseLocks();
            }
            if (c != null) {
                try {
                    c.rollback();
                    c.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    //nothing to do
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: what is contexts?

Comment: and what if I don't want to use contexts?

Comment: Try using empty string like ```new Contexts("");``` I haven't tried this but may be you can give it a try.